# Priority inversion

Tags: multithreading, computer-science

I am having problem understanding [Priority Inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_inversion)

Snippet from the article:

> Consider there is a task L, with low
>   priority. This task requires resource
>   R. Consider that L is running and it
>   acquires resource R. Now, there is
>   another task H, with high priority.
>   This task also requires resource R.
>   Consider H starts after L has acquired
>   resource R. Now H has to wait until L
>   relinquishes resource R.
>
> Everything works as expected up to
>   this point, but problems arise when a
>   new task M starts with medium priority
>   during this time. ` Since R is still
>   in use (by L), H cannot run. Since M
>   is the highest priority unblocked
>   task, it will be scheduled before L.
>   Since L has been preempted by M, L
>   cannot relinquish R. So M will run
>   till it is finished, then L will run -
>   at least up to a point where it can
>   relinquish R - and then H will run.
>   Thus, in above scenario, a task with
>   medium priority ran before a task with
>   high priority, effectively giving us a
>   priority inversion.

The question is relevant to the second part of the article. Why is that a process with H (Higher) priority cannot pre-empt a process with L (lower) priority but a process with M (medium) priority can pre-empt? i.e. If H was put to block since R was in use, why was M not blocked as well ?

Comment: This smells like homework.  Still, a good question.

Comment: Not sure how or why ..but it is not...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because M does not require resource R, so it is able to run while L still has it in use; H, on the other hand, cannot run until L is able to release R.